How do I use Chronicle Jars in a Java project if the sun.misc class used in Chronicle Jars is no longer available in JDK 11 and 17?
I am encountering the following error while deploying a Java WAR file in a WildFly server using JDK 17. The error seems to be related to the Chronicle library:


09:26:39,705 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-1) UT005023: Exception handling request to /CQService/CQWriter: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link net/openhft/chronicle/core/Jvm$ChainedSignalHandler (Module "deployment.CQService.war" from Service Module Loader): sun/misc/SignalHandler
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1017)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1095)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:351)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:482)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:276)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:79)
        at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:798)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:192)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:408)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:396)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:115)
        at deployment.CQService.war//net.openhft.chronicle.core.Jvm.<clinit>(Jvm.java:163)
        at deployment.CQService.war//net.openhft.chronicle.core.OS.<clinit>(OS.java:53)
        at deployment.CQService.war//net.openhft.chronicle.queue.impl.single.SingleChronicleQueueBuilder.<clinit>(SingleChronicleQueueBuilder.java:68)
        at deployment.CQService.war//com.bp.tm.servlet.CQWriterServlet.doPost(CQWriterServlet.java:39)
        at jakarta.servlet.api@6.0.0//jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:547)
        at jakarta.servlet.api@6.0.0//jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:614)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.13.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.13.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.13.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.13.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
        at org.wildfly.security.elytron-web.undertow-server@4.1.0.Final//org.wildfly.elytron.web.undertow.server.ElytronRunAsHandler.lambda$handleRequest$1(ElytronRunAsHandler.java:68)
        at org.wildfly.security.elytron-base@2.4.2.Final//org.wildfly.security.auth.server.FlexibleIdentityAssociation.runAsFunctionEx(FlexibleIdentityAssociation.java:103)
        at org.wildfly.security.elytron-base@2.4.2.Final//org.wildfly.security.auth.server.Scoped.runAsFunctionEx(Scoped.java:161)
        at org.wildfly.security.elytron-base@2.4.2.Final//org.wildfly.security.auth.server.Scoped.runAs(Scoped.java:73)
        at org.wildfly.security.elytron-web.undertow-server@4.1.0.Final//org.wildfly.elytron.web.undertow.server.ElytronRunAsHandler.handleRequest(ElytronRunAsHandler.java:67)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.13.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.RedirectDirHandler.handleRequest(RedirectDirHandler.java:68)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.13.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:117)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.13.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
        at io.undertow.core@2.3.13.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.core@2.3.13.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.13.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
        at io.undertow.core@2.3.13.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.security.elytron-web.undertow-server-servlet@4.1.0.Final//org.wildfly.elytron.web.undertow.server.servlet.CleanUpHandler.handleRequest(CleanUpHandler.java:38)
        at io.undertow.core@2.3.13.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@32.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:44)
        at io.undertow.core@2.3.13.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@32.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:51)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.13.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.SendErrorPageHandler.handleRequest(SendErrorPageHandler.java:52)
        at io.undertow.core@2.3.13.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.13.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:276)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.13.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.13.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:132)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.13.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.13.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@32.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1421)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@32.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1421)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@32.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1421)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@32.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1421)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.13.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:256)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.13.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:101)
        at io.undertow.core@2.3.13.Final//io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:393)
        at io.undertow.core@2.3.13.Final//io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:859)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1348)
        at org.jboss.xnio@3.8.15.Final//org.xnio.XnioWorker$WorkerThreadFactory$1$1.run(XnioWorker.java:1282)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.misc.SignalHandler from [Module "deployment.CQService.war" from Service Module Loader]
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:200)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:408)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:396)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:115)
        ... 60 more`



this error i m getting in wildlfly logs while deploying war file in wildly server in this war file i m getting this error while running automation script ..and it will call post method in CQWriter

here is wildfly server logs -

09:26:39,705 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-1) UT005023: Exception handling request to /CQService/CQWriter: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link net/openhft/chronicle/core/Jvm$ChainedSignalHandler (Module "deployment.CQService.war" from Service Module Loader): sun/misc/SignalHandler
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1017)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1095)

You should edit your question and post the full stack trace so we can see which class is causing it.

The issue we're encountering is related to the sun.misc.SignalHandler class not being found in the current Java environment. This class is part of the sun.misc package, which is not part of the standard Java SE API and is not guaranteed to be available in all Java environments.
The sun.misc package was part of older Java versions, but it's not available in the latest Java versions, starting from Java 9 onwards. It looks like the Chronicle library we're using relies on this package, which causes a NoClassDefFoundError when the application is deployed.

May be you should read the documentation https://chronicle.software/chronicle-support-java-17/

The latest version(s) [ definded in Chronicle-BOM: 2.26ea21 ] of chronicle code works with java 11 and java 17. please try to update to the latest version of the chronicle code.

i am using latest chronicle  jar files  chronicle 2.21.

@AsmitaSharma 2.21 is no longer supported and probably doesn't work for Java 17+. I suggest you upgrade to a 2.24.x, 2.25.x or 2.26.x chronicle-bom as these are supported for Java 17. https://github.com/OpenHFT/OpenHFT/blob/ea/docs/Version-Support.adoc

Hi @PeterLawrey , I am using 2.25 version now   with jdk 11  still i m getting same error 11:48:02,776 ERROR [com.bp.tm.servlet.CQWriterServlet] (default task-1) Error in CQWriterServlet: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link net/openhft/chronicle/core/Jvm$ChainedSignalHandler (Module "deployment.CQService.war" from Service Module Loader): sun/misc/SignalHandler
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1022)

Are you setting the required flags?                    --illegal-access=permit
--add-exports java.base/jdk.internal.misc=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-exports java.base/jdk.internal.ref=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-exports java.base/jdk.internal.util=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-exports java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED
https://search.maven.org/artifact/net.openhft/root-parent-pom/1.26.0/pom
